# sorting a list in python based on difference from a value

Tags: python, list, sorting

Anyone knows how to sort a list using a value as a reference?. For example I have the following list:

```
1,3,5,10,12
```

and the single value `7`, the output would be:

```
5,10,3,12,1
```

thanks!

Comment: Questions shouldn't be quizzes. Make sure to explain why the output should derive from the input.

Comment: @Jamylak gave you a correct answer.  If you want to learn how to find your own answer, read this:  http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html

Comment: @RaymondHettinger have often wondered if that example should use `methodcaller('lower')` as key, rather than hard-typing `str`

Comment: @JonClements probably don't want to deal with that first off in a tutorial

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> nums = [1,3,5,10,12]
>>> sorted(nums, key=lambda x: abs(7 - x))
[5, 10, 3, 12, 1]
```

Sorting in-place:

```
>>> nums.sort(key=lambda x: abs(7 - x))
>>> nums
[5, 10, 3, 12, 1]
```

Comment: Gets the output requested... and good guess at requirement - shame it wasn't stated better

Comment: @jamylak it works with 7, but I need to pass 7 as a parameter, example 

tar = 6
nums.sort(key=lambda x: abs(tar - x))